# Attempted to read or write protected memory from Resources.Image

Tags: c#

In the background I use a DLL for pooling data from PCI-e bus via DMA. If I run only the DLL without to update the status I can run for hours.

I receive the follow exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often indication that other memory is corrupt.

I recived this error when I try to change button image from resources.

Code:

```
statusButton.Image=Resources.Status_Ok;
```

Or

```
statusButton.Image=Resources.Status_Fail;
```

The exception does not appear all the time!

The command is fetch by timer (`System.Timers.Timer`).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to load something into your UI from a background process (i.e. your timer) which will always attempt to lock your main thread to paint.  You need to control that locking or you will run into locking issues - especially if you are interacting with your app or if you have long running main thread operations.

Check out the background worker thread to run your DLL - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841751/MultiThreading-Using-a-Background-Worker-Csharp - as that will probably fix your issue.